# (gdb) prompt does not return after start

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I have a very simple Hello World c++ program. I am running it on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5.  Apple LLVM version 10.0.1. GNU gdb (GDB) 8.3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with command `g++ -g a.cpp`

I run gdb as `sudo gdb ./a.out`.

In `(gdb)` prompt I type `start`

I get the following message, but the `(gdb)` prompt never returns:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f3f: file a.cpp, line 6.
Starting program: a.out 
[New Thread 0x1203 of process 5444]
[New Thread 0xf03 of process 5444]
```

I cannot even close the process with `control + z`. I have to force a termination of the terminal to close it.

Comment: Platform? Version of things?

Comment: Why do not you end gdb with the quit command?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit added missing data.

Comment: @stark Using sudo as a quick fix because I have not created a certificate. Mac OS requires that.

Comment: Not sure if gdb properly supports llvm, have you tried lldb?

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba How do you do that without a prompt?

Comment: I suspect your gdb session gets "backgrounded". What is the output of the `jobs` command? `sudo jobs`? Does `fg` bring gdb back? What if you do `sudo -i` before everything (if you absolutely must use sudo for running gdb)?

Comment: in fact, what process do you write about "gdb", "I can not even close the process"? "process 5444"? About the terminal? What exactly do you want to send to the background (not close!) using CTRL + Z?